# Are aircraft sounds publicly available in a repository?

Tags: boeing, airbus, website, noise, fwc

Referring to the automated callouts and sounds made by the [fwc](/questions/tagged/fwc), [tcas](/questions/tagged/tcas), [gpws](/questions/tagged/gpws), [pws](/questions/tagged/pws), etc. — are these available to download in one repository at all? For any aircraft, Airbus or Boeing.

Understandably, these may not be *freely* available, but I'm curious otherwise too (e.g. the likes of Air Crash Investigation must do this).

Comment: This is really more of an Audio/Video question.  Yes the sounds are of airplanes, but the main gist of the question is sound as it relates to audio recordings...

Comment: See also: [Should we allow questions asking for resources?](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/15)

Comment: Right, but you aren't asking for an aviation resource here you're asking for an audio resource (at least that's my opinion).  Understand, my purpose in pointing this out is to try and get this question to a group that can be more helpful, like a forum or stack that deals with recorded audio.

Answer (score 3):

One place to look is models of the planes for flight simulators. There is generally a "sounds" folder of some sort inside the airplane folder that includes some cockpit sounds.

I'm guessing the original files are proprietary and there is really no reason for the companies to freely share them. Shows like Air Crash Investigation might get access to a simulator that can make all the real sounds.

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick google search and [this was a link that I found](https://www.sounddogs.com/results.asp?Type=1&CategoryID=1005&SubcategoryID=5).  Although, the quality of these samples leaves a lot to be desired.